# Unresponsive UI after using a link to safari

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Throughout my app, I have buttons and navigation links that take the user out of the app and to safari. When returning to the app, the UI becomes unresponsive. You have to tap things multiple times for it to register. Maybe the main thread is being blocked, causing unresponsive UI?

I can't seem to find what the issue is.

Here is an example of where I am taking the user out of the app and into safari. When the "Privacy Policy" button is tapped, the user is taken to safari.

```
struct SettingsSheet: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
           
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            ZStack {                
                VStack {
                    VStack {                        
                        List {
                            
                            Section(header: Text("Account Settings")) {
                                
                                NavigationLink(

                                    destination: HelpView(),

                                    label: {
                                        Text("Help")
                                    })
                                
                                NavigationLink(

                                    destination: RateAppView(),

                                    label: {
                                        Text("Rate This App")
                                    })
                                
                                NavigationLink(

                                    destination: NotificationsView(),

                                    label: {
                                        Text("Notifications")
                                    })
                                
                                NavigationLink(

                                    destination: LogOutView(),

                                    label: {
                                        Text("Log Out")
                                    })
                                
                            }
                            .headerProminence(.increased)
                            
                            Section(header: Text("Information")) {

                                Button(action: {
                                    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://www.stackoverflow.com")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                                }) {
                                    Text("Privacy Policy")
                                }
                                                                
                                NavigationLink(

                                    destination: DeleteAccountView(),

                                    label: {
                                        Text("Delete Account")
                                    })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Settings")
    }
}
```

The UI unresponsiveness seems to occur in the Tab Bar. Here is the code for my Tab Bar:

```
struct MainPage: View {

    @StateObject var AppModel: AppViewModel = .init()
    @Namespace var animation
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 0){
            
            TabView(selection: $AppModel.currentTab) {
                
                View1()
                    .tag(Tab.View1)
                    .setUpTab()
                
                View2()
                    .tag(Tab.View2)
                    .setUpTab()
                
                View3()
                    .tag(Tab.View3)
                    .setUpTab()
        
                View4()
                    .tag(Tab.View4)
                    .setUpTab()
                
                View5()
                    .tag(Tab.View5)
                    .setUpTab()
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                CustomTabBar(currentTab: $AppModel.currentTab, animation: animation)                    
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
    }
}
```

```
struct CustomTabBar: View {
    @Binding var currentTab: Tab
    var animation: Namespace.ID
    // Current Tab XValue...
    @State var currentXValue: CGFloat = 0
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0){
            ForEach(Tab.allCases,id: \.rawValue){tab in
                TabButton(tab: tab)
                    .overlay {
                        Text(tab.rawValue)
                            .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .semibold))
                            .foregroundColor(Color("TileText"))
                            .offset(y: currentTab == tab ? 15 : 100)
                    }
            }
        }
        .padding(.top)
        // Preview wont show safeArea...
        .padding(.bottom,getSafeArea().bottom == 0 ? 15 : 10)
        .background{
//            Color.white
            Color("TileColour")
                .shadow(color: Color("Black").opacity(0.08), radius: 5, x: 0, y: -5)
                .clipShape(BottomCurve(currentXValue: currentXValue))
                .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .bottom)
        }
    }
    // TabButton...
    @ViewBuilder
    func TabButton(tab: Tab)->some View{
        // Since we need XAxis Value for Curve...
        GeometryReader{proxy in
            Button {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut){
                    currentTab = tab
                    // updating Value...
                    currentXValue = proxy.frame(in: .global).midX
                }
                
            } label: {
                // Moving Button up for current Tab...
                Image(tab.rawValue)
                // Since we need perfect value for Curve...
                    .resizable()
                    .renderingMode(.template)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .foregroundColor(currentTab == tab ? .white : .gray.opacity(0.8))
                    .padding(currentTab == tab ? 15 : 0)
                    .background(
                        ZStack{
                            if currentTab == tab{
                                Circle()
                                    .fill(Color("LightBlue"))
                                    .shadow(color: Color("Black").opacity(0.1), radius: 8, x: 5, y: 5)
                                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "TAB", in: animation)
                            }
                        }
                    )
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .offset(y: currentTab == tab ? -50 : 0)
            }
            // Setting intial Curve Position...
            .onAppear {
                
                if tab == Tab.allCases.first && currentXValue == 0{
                    
                    currentXValue = proxy.frame(in: .global).midX
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 30)
    }
}

// Making Case Iteratable...
// Tab Cases...
enum Tab: String,CaseIterable{

    case View1 = "View1"
    case View2 = "View2"
    case View3 = "View3"
    case View4 = "View4"
    case View5 = "View5"

}

// Getting Safe Area...
extension View{
    func getSafeArea()->UIEdgeInsets{
        guard let screen = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene else{
            return .zero
        }
        
        guard let safeArea = screen.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets else{
            return .zero
        }
        
        return safeArea
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what is causing this and any solutions?

Comment: Interesting, did you try to wrap the  open(..) method into a dispatch queue main async? maybe running on the next runloop solves the problem

Comment: FYI: I tried your code, replacing the Destinations with Text("1"), but i had no unresponsive UI. Did you tried on a different device?

Comment: @LoVo I hadn't tried that! The UI issues happens on my iPhone however when I run the app on the simulator, the UI bug is not there. Any ideas on why? Maybe a reinstall will fix it on the iPhone?

Comment: @LoVo I just tried a reinstall but it didn't fix the error. Any ideas on a solution?

Comment: Maybe the problem is not the code you posted, could you try to replace the destinations one by one to check if one of them leads to your unresponsive UI?
BTW: SwiftUI has a Link view which offers the same functionality as your button.
e.g.: `Link("Privacy Policy", destination: URL(string: "https://www.stackoverflow.com")!)`

Comment: @LoVo this is certainly a better way to use the link. The issue still exists though. I have noticed that the UI unresponsiveness seems to be affecting the Tab bar of the app. Maybe there is an issue there. I will update the question to show the code for this.